# Discord.js Unban all users

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello I am trying to make a command in discord.js that unbans all banned users however when i execute the ub all command it says unbanned all but doesn't unban anyone,this is my code so far

```
    bot.on('message', message =>{
    const member = message.member; 
    switch(message.content.toLowerCase()){
        case (PREFIX + "ub all"):
    if(member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')){ 
        async function ubAll(){
        const users = await message.guild.fetchBans()
        for (const user of users.array()) {
        await message.guild.unban(user)
        }
    }
message.reply("Unbanned all users from the server.")
        }
    if(!member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')){
        message.reply("You do not have enough permissions for this command!")
    }
    }
})
```

Comment: Which version of Discord JS are you using? You can check that in `package.json`.

Comment: I am using discord.js: 12.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unban` is not a method of `guild`. You need to use `guild.members.unban()`.

---

```js
bot.on("message", message => {
    switch(message.content.toLowerCase()) {
        case (PREFIX + "ub all"):
            if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
                message.guild.fetchBans().then(bans => {
                    if (bans.size == 0) {message.reply("There are no banned users."); throw "No members to unban."};
                    bans.forEach(ban => {
                        message.guild.members.unban(ban.user.id);
                    });
                }).then(() => message.reply("Unbanned all users.")).catch(e => console.log(e))
            } else {message.reply("You do not have enough permissions for this command.")}
        break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
bot.on('message', message =>{
    const member = message.member; 
    switch(message.content.toLowerCase()){
    case (PREFIX + "ub all"):
        if(member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')){
            message.guild.fetchBans().forEach((fB)=>{
                message.guild.members.unban(fB.user.id);
            })
            // All Users get unbanned
        } else {
            // User does not have permission.
        }
    }
})
```

I strongly suggest to take a peek at the Discord.JS v12 documentation.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring the `ubAll` function but not actually calling it.
You can also replace the last `if` by `else`.

```
bot.on("message", async (message) => {
  const member = message.member;
  switch (message.content.toLowerCase()) {
    case PREFIX + "ub all":
      if (member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
        const users = await message.guild.fetchBans();
        for (const user of users.array()) {
          await message.guild.unban(user);
        }
        message.reply("Unbanned all users from the server.");
      } else
        message.reply("You do not have enough permissions for this command!");
    }
});
```